# Symfony2/Twig - Add classes to form elements

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've just started a new Symfony2 project where I've used the `generate:doctrine:crud` to quickly scale out a few views, forms, etc.

The generated form code is just:
`{{ form(form) }}` but includes a generic create or delete button. I was wondering how I could add a class to these generic buttons or modify them in any way since it's just encompassed in `{{ form(form) }}`?

For reference I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to quickly apply some styles so I don't want to change the css based on the submit button.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Read more about Symfony's form themes in general: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html 2. If you're using TW Bootstrap you might be interested in this: http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/

Comment: Just add a twitter bootstrap btn-class directly from the FormBuilder like this: 'attr'=> array('class'=>'btn btn-alert')

Answer (score 1):

You can specify CSS classes in the form builder class to avoid filling your Twig template with html even for rendering the form individually.

When you call `{{ form(form) }}` you are using a helper to simplify your code so you don't have to call `form_widget` for each one of your fields, but doing so you can't control the exact display in the template. To do it you have to specify the class that will be applied to the field.

In the `WhateverType.php` file, inside the `Forms` folder, you have the form builder. There you should have something like:

```
   $builder
        ->add('text')
        ->add('whatever')
```

There you have to add the classes:

```
   $builder
        ->add('text', 'attr'=> array('class'=>'btn')
        ->add('whatever')
```

Then, when your form is displayed in the template, it will apply the classes that you specified in the builder.

Answer (score 1):

After following [dmnptr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044749/3455675) (breaking form into parts), you can pass an array of arguments to each `form` / `form_row` / `form_label` etc by:

```
{{ form(form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'your-css-class-1 your-css-class-2' } } ) }}
```

The `attr` param sets attributes for the item, so the above would produce:

```
<form class="your-css-class-1 your-css-class-2" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to render each filed by hand and add necessary classes to elements in your `TWIG`. Read on how to do it in the official docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand